# Command Extensions Load But Don't Appear In Discord

Tags: python, discord.py, pycord

I've been cleaning up my Discord bot and wanted to split the commands into separate files.

I've put the commands for the bot in separate files, gave them a setup function. The bot ran fine, the loaded commands printed their setup prints (all the code will be below) but the slash commands don't work nor show up in the Discord autofill. The only thing that could be causing this as far as I'm aware is the load_extension function so I've removed it from my bot for the time being, but any help would be appreciated.

The main file

```
import discord
bot = discord.Bot()
intents = discord.Intents.all()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(str(bot.user) + ' has connected to Discord!')

bot.load_extension("Commands")

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

One of the shorter commands

```
import discord
bot = discord.Bot()

def setup(bot):
    print("Hey is being unloaded!")

@bot.slash_command()
async def hey(ctx):  # Library automatically converts type annotations, just like in discord.py
    print(f"Sending message to {ctx.author.name} id: = {ctx.author.id}")
    await ctx.respond(f"Hello! I'm {str(bot.user)[:-5]}!\n\nOr am I?")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why def setup does just print. Also usually, cogs work like that:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class CogName(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot:commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot


    @commands.command(name = "commandName",
                    usage="<usage>",
                    description = "description")
    async def commandName(self, ctx:commands.Context):
        await ctx.respond("template command")


def setup(bot:commands.Bot):
    bot.add_cog(CogName(bot))
```

So:fix: Class, Commands, Setup
In cogs: from discord.ext import commands @commands.slash_command and not bot...
I suggest reading the documentation on [cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html).

Answer (score 0):

A simple example for implementing `slash commands` for your main.py file (without cogs) [PY-CORD]

```
import discord

#Defining Intents
intents = discord.Intents.all() #Tts `.all()` means every intent will be on
bot = discord.Bot(intents=intents, debug_guilds=["put your guild id here"]) #Loading intents here as well as guild for which you can load/test your slash commands

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(str(bot.user) + ' has connected to Discord!') #you can also use f' string here as you did inside your hey function

@bot.slash_command()
async def hey(interaction: discord.Interaction): #`discord.Interaction` defining the type for interaction
    print(f"Sending message to {interaction.author.name} id: = {interaction.author.id}")
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Hello! I'm {str(bot.user)[:-5]}!\n\nOr am I?")

bot.run(TOKEN) #Put your [Bot TOKEN] in `TOKEN` place
```

**Why your code wasn't working?**

- You forgot to load your created `intents` in `discord.Bot()`.
  Discord may take some time to load slash commands, especially for public bots. --To speed up testing or for personal bots with fewer servers, you can specify the server ID in the `debug_ids` list, which will make your commands available instantly for that server. However, for public usage, ensure everything is correctly loaded as previously mentioned, and be patient as slash commands may load late, but they will eventually load in the end.

**Can't I use `ctx` as normally? and Why did I changed it to `interaction`:**

-Yes, you can still use `ctx` to send messages within the `hey function` just like your code.
However, the reason for changing it to `interaction` is that you're now dealing with a user-initiated ***interaction***. When a user triggers your command, it starts an interaction. While using `ctx` will technically work, it might show an "***interaction failed***" message in **Discord**.

-To ensure clarity and a clean, effective *interaction*, it's **recommended** to use `interaction`. When you answer an **interaction**, you should reply using the interaction object. You can continue to use `ctx` for [regular commands](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html) and stick to interaction for [interaction-based-commands](https://guide.pycord.dev/interactions/application-commands/slash-commands).

-Avoid mixing them and to ensure a smoother experience for user in Discord as well in your code.

*Also it is really important to understand what every line in your code do so please try reading documentation for **py-cord*** [here](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/quickstart.html).

Also for making **cogs** please check [this](https://guide.pycord.dev/popular-topics/cogs#:%7E:text=Creating%20Commands%E2%80%8B&text=In%20a%20cog%2C%20you%20can,slash_command()%20%2C%20%40discord.)

**How to get guild ids for testing interaction commands?**

Assuming you have a server to test:
Go `Discord Settings-->Advanced-->Turn **On** Developer Mode`.
Once done you can **right-click** on your **server/guild** and **copy** the **id** from the clicking `Copy Server ID` from the **options**.

*Hope I helped, Keep Learning:D*